# Get id of dragged element in d3.js

Tags: d3.js, reactjs

I am probably having some kind of brain damage atm because something like **this should be trivial**.

I got a bunch of SVG circles rendered manually (via React). I am then attaching d3 drag behavior to all of them. The drag behavior is applied, and the drag function is being executed, but when I drag one of these circles I am not able to respond accordingly because I do not know which one of them was moved. **Where can I get the ID of dragged element**?

I have checked a few other questions and found just some crazy filter solution... that cannot be it.

I have also peeked at [docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-drag#drag_on) and found the `subject` property.. however that one is null everywhere I tried it.

My code:

```
componentWillUpdate() {
  let nodes = d3.selectAll("circle");

  const dragFn = (d,i) => {
    d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();
    this.props.onNodeDrag(I_NEED_AN_ID_HERE);
  }

  const dragBehavior = d3.behavior.drag();
  dragBehavior.on('drag', dragFn);
  dragBehavior.on('dragstart', () => {
    d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();
  });

  nodes.call(dragBehavior);
}
```

Comment: Please don't edit the answer in your question! See: [*"Is it OK for users to edit the accepted answer into their question?"*](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262806), [*"Is it better to answer or edit your question to post solution?"*](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307553), [*"Editing self-answer out of question"*](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278050) etc. Put it in a self-answer if you think the existing answer isn't specific enough.

Comment: @altocumulus: ok, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know what your "this" is inside the function but in plain js you can get any attribute of the html element with:

```
d3.select(this).attr("id"); //or class etc.
```

or if it's wrapped

```
 d3.select(this).select("circle").attr("id");
```

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/a2QpA/343/

Comment: Thanks, that did it :) I have changed the code a bit to preserve the this context and used the d3.select(this). Will update the question and accept this answer in a bit.